# Доступ к элементу подкаталога из файла другого подкаталога Php + Apache2

Tags: php, css, apache

Не знал как правильно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому вы его видете таким, каким он есть. Ниже описана ситуация, в которой возникает проблема, что бы было понятней о чем идет речь.

Ситуация следующая:
Разрабатываю сайт, структура примерно такая:

```
    1) structure (*каталог где хранятся элементы встраиваемые в другие страницы*)  
    1.1) logo.php  
    1.2) menu_side.php  
    1.3) footer.php    
    2) pages (*каталог хранит основные страницы*)  
    2.1) moskow_info (*подкаталог, где хранятся информация о городе вместе с картинками и страницами*) 
    -moscow.php  
    2.2) spb_info  
    -spb.php  
    2.3) rostov_info  
  -rostov.php  
3) images  
- logo.png
```

Допустим, мне нужно вставить **logo.php во все страницы** типа moscow.php, spb.php, rostov.php. Делаю это так:

```
<header id="header">  
<?php   
     include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/structure/logo.php";
?>   
</header>
```

В свою очень, **logo.php содержит ссылку на картинку**, в виде такого когда:

```
<?php  
$a = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/logo.png"; ?>
<a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo $a; ?>" /></a>
```

Вызываю страницу **test.ru/pages/moscow.php**. По идее, **должна отобразиться картинка из logo.php**, но изображение данным образом не отображается. Когда открываю **Исходных код страницы**, там видно что **путь прописывается правильно**:

```
<a href="index.php"><img src="C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.4/htdocs/region.ru/www/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в непонимании того, что есть уровень файловой системы и уровень документов веб-сервера. Разберемся.

### Как работает веб-сервер

Когда на веб-сервер прилетает запрос "дай мне документ `/images/logo.png`", то веб-сервер "складывает" корень веб-документов и путь к запрашиваемому документу.

Apache: корень веб-документов прописывается так:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # виртуальный хост
  ServerName site.ru
  # корень веб-документов
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/www
  # остальные настройки
</VirtualHost>
```

Если у вас Nginx, то так:

```
server {
  # порт
  listen              80;
  # виртуальный хост
  server_name         site.ru;
  # корень веб-документов
  root                /var/www/site.ru/www;
  # остальные настройки
}
```

Таким образом, получается `/var/www/site.ru/www` + `/images/logo.png` = `/var/www/site.ru/www/images/logo.png` - это абсолютный путь к файлу в файловой системе, веб-сервер находит этот документ, и отправляет пользователю в браузер.

### Как работает PHP

PHP - это всего лишь скрипт, который запускается веб-сервером. Если в нем будет строчка

```
include_once "/structure/logo.php";
```

то PHP не найдет этот файл, ведь этот путь от корня файловой системы. В этом и заключается отличие от веб-сервера, который будет смотреть не с `/`, а с корня веб-документов.

### Резюме

Используйте в PHP абсолютный путь:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/structure/logo.php";
```

используйте в генерируемом HTML не `C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.4/htdocs/region.ru/www/images/logo.png`, а

```
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```

веб-сервером это будет преобразовано в абсолютный путь с учетом корня веб-документов и отправлено по HTTP в браузер

Comment: Большое спасибо за столь подробный ответ! Действительно, не усмотрел слеш.